# PyTorch Tensor assignment issue -- tensor[1, 1] = tensor([4.], device='mps:0') -> val is on pos [0, 0]

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I'm learning PyTorch and I came accros this issues while playing on same course code

```
empty_tensor = torch.zeros((2,2))
r_tensor = torch.tensor([4]).to(device).float()
print(r_tensor)
>>> tensor([4.], device='mps:0')

empty_tensor[1, 1] = r_tensor
print(empty_tensor)
>>>tensor([[4., 0.],
        [0., 0.]])
```

Are normally, I should get the result as

```
>>>tensor([[0., 0.],
        [0., 4.]])
```

### Versionning:

- Python3.10
- PyTorch2.1 nightly

Don't think other version is required

### What I tryed

I try by assigning a single float, like

```
empty_tensor[1, 1] = 1
```

And it work well, think its maybe about how PyTorch is dealing with slicing maybe, something I didn't get yet

Comment: How was `r_tensor` defined?

Comment: my bad -> r_tensor is random_tensor
Typo error I'll fix it 

Comment: Does your code work as expected if you keep r_tensor on cpu?

Comment: Yup actually it work if I keep only the r_tensor to cpu `r_tensor = torch.tensor([4]).float()`
I guess form this output, I can't concatenate tensor from a cpu device and a tensor from a gpu device ?

Comment: Thanks for the response Yakov, and Ivan to spot the typo error 